# "ps" returning "No namelist" on UNIX V7

Tags: unix

I am using this emulator for UNIX V7: http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/pdp11.htm

When I type `ps` to get a list of processes, I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot indicating "No Namelist"]

Comment: See also the followup https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/how-to-get-a-list-of-processes-on-unix-v7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ps` in V7 expects to find the unstripped kernel binary in [`/unix`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/ps.c#L104), or named as the *second* parameter. In the Sanos simulator, you should run

```
cd /
ln rl2unix unix
```

to set the `/unix` link up correctly.

That won’t fix `ps` completely though, it fails looking for `/dev/swap`... I don’t know what the node should be for that, none of the values in `/dev/makefile` work.

Comment: So the problem is from the Sanos simulator?

Comment: Not with Sanos, with the V7 image I think.

Comment: What sort of insane hackery are they using to require a kernel binary to run `ps`?!?!

Comment: @Muzer, in V7, `ps` reads the kernel’s data structures in memory directly, there isn’t a nice interface between the kernel and userspace. `ps` needs the namelist from the kernel to determine where the process map is located. See [`nlist(3)`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man3/nlist.3) and [`a.out(5)`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man5/a.out.5) for details (this is where I notice that GitHub now formats troff... nice...).

Comment: Yep, before procfs and equivalents were introduced, that's how ps did it :)

Comment: ...and far more modern systems still had these kind of mechanics: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/muc.lists.netbsd.tech.kern/RdMgGAv9xHc

Comment: @rackandboneman which gives a sense of the timescales involved, when IRIX counts as “far more modern” ;-).

Comment: It was used on production systems up into the 2000s, no?

Comment: @rackandboneman yes, it was available until 2006 and supported until 2013, but it had been in maintenance mode since at least 1998 (when 6.5 was released). I don’t think it changed much after 6.0 in 1994...

Comment: I’d imagine it’s still in use on production systems somewhere, actually.